# Skip an entry of a random iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Suppose we have a function `foo` that does *something* 
to all the elements between `*firsta` and `*lastb`:

```
foo(RandomAccessIterator1 firsta,RandomAccessIterator1 lasta){
    for (RandomAccessIterator1 it=firsta;it!=lasta+1;it++){
            //here stuff happens...
    }    
}
```

question a): is there a way to skip an index  `firsta<i<lastb` by only 
modifying the inputs to `foo` --e.g. the random iterators, 
in other words without changing `foo` itself, just its input?

--Unfortunately the index I want to skip are not in the edges 
(they are often deep between `firsta` and `lasta`) and `foo` 
 is a complicated divide&conquer algorithm that's not amenable 
to being called on subsets of the original array the iterators 
are pointing to.

question b): if doing a) is possible, what's the cost of doing that?
constant or does it depend on `(lasta-firsta)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use an iterator that knows how to skip that element.  A more generalized idea though, is an iterator that simply iterates over two separate ranges under the hood.  I don't know of anything in boost that does this, so, here's one I just whipped up:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/588afa2a353942fc

Unfortunately, the code to detect which element to skip adds a teeny tiny amount of overhead to each and every iterator increment, so the overhead is technically proportional to `lasta-firsta`.  Realistically, using this wrapper around a `vector::iterator` or a `char*` should bring it roughly to the same performance level as `std::deque::iterator`, so it's not like this should be a major slowdown.

Comment: Just occurred to me that `boost::filter_iterator` could have been used, though it's less obvious what the overhead would be.

Comment: thanks sire...I'll try this~ At any rate, it's much more complicated than I though!

Comment: @user189035: Well, note that you can just copy-paste the iterator itself into a header, and then all you have to do to use it is the `auto range = concatenate_ranges(...)` bit.  It's complicated because this version is very flexible.  It doesn't just skip one element, it can do any number of things.  Such as "concatenating" several structures.

Comment: @MooingDuck: thanks: the more I use your construction, the more I find it robust and elegant...

Comment: @user189035: I've been thinking of how to extend it to concatenating several ranges and/or different iterator types, but turns out those are tricky

Comment: @MooingDuck: to be honnest (selfish), the answer as it stands fill *perfectly* my needs. I was surprised at first that something so handy was not in STL, but your answer is the next best thing!

Comment: Here's a first pass at an iterator that can concatenate several ranges, but it needs additional work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8b2c2d3106021b7

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be a bit picky, but you could call `foo(firsta,i-1)` and `foo(i+1,lastb)` or something similar to have the desired effect.