# Adapting a custom iterator so that so that (a?) reverse_iterator can flip it's output

Tags: c++, iterator

Recently, user @Mooing Duck designed [`concatenated_range`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767661/189035),  an elegant custom iterator that solves the problem of 'chaining' two iterators, all under the hood.

It works great for it's intended usage:

```
auto range0=concatenate_ranges(x,x+i-1,x+i,x+a5+1);
a6=foo(range0.first,range0.second);
```

Now, I want to adapt it, by doing (example #2):

```
auto range0=concatenate_ranges(x+a5+1,x+i-1,x+i+1,x+n);
a6=foo(std::reverse_iterator<float*>(range0.second),std::reverse_iterator<float*>(range0.first));
```

Needless to say, the compiler isn't happy. An alternative (not sure if the ordering is right here):

```
auto range0=concatenate_ranges(std::reverse_iterator<float*>(x+n),x+i+1,x+i-1,std::reverse_iterator<float*>(x+a5[i]+1));
a6=foo(range0.first,range0.second);
```

Isn't taken for granted either :(.

My question is: how can I adapt `concatenate_ranges()` so that it's output can be
fed into `std::reverse_iterator` (as in the second example above). Also, I don't mind
using `boost::` if it makes things easier.

## EDIT:

user @Jack reports that the link in the original answer doesn't display the code for him. I don't know how widespread that problem is, so for clarity I reproduce the code I refer to here (please refer to the original answer for the explanation):

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

template<class base>
class concatenated_range_iterator 
    : public boost::iterator_facade<
        concatenated_range_iterator<base>,
        typename std::iterator_traits<base>::value_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<base>::iterator_category,
        typename std::iterator_traits<base>::reference,
        typename std::iterator_traits<base>::difference_type
        >
{
public:
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<base>::iterator_category iterator_category;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<base>::value_type        value_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<base>::difference_type   difference_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<base>::pointer           pointer;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<base>::reference         reference;
    
    concatenated_range_iterator() = default;
    concatenated_range_iterator(bool begin, base begin1, base end1, base begin2, base end2) 
        :current(begin?begin1:end2), end_first(end1), begin_second(begin2), in_first(begin)
        {}
        
    reference dereference() {return *current;}
    reference dereference() const {return *current;}
    bool equal(const concatenated_range_iterator& rhs) const {
        assert(end_first==rhs.end_first);
        assert(begin_second==rhs.begin_second);
        return in_first==rhs.in_first && current==rhs.current;
    }
    void increment() {
        ++current;
        if (in_first) {
            if (current==end_first) {
                current = begin_second;
                in_first = false;
            }
        } 
    }
    void decrement() {
        if (!in_first) {
            if (current==begin_second) {
                current = end_first;
                in_first = true;
            }
        }
        --current;
    }
    void advance(difference_type n) {
        if (n>=0) {
            if (in_first) {
                difference_type safe = end_first-current;
                if (safe <= n) {
                    current = begin_second;
                    n -= safe;
                    in_first = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!in_first) {
                difference_type safe = current-begin_second;
                if (safe <= n) {
                    current = end_first;
                    n += safe;
                    in_first = true;
                }
            }
        }
        current += n;
    }
    difference_type distance_to(const concatenated_range_iterator& rhs) const {
        assert(end_first==rhs.end_first);
        assert(begin_second==rhs.begin_second);
        if (in_first) {
            if (rhs.in_first) 
                return rhs.current-current;
            else
                return rhs.current-begin_second + end_first-current;
        } else {
            if (rhs.in_first) 
                return rhs.current-end_first + begin_second-current;
            else
                return rhs.current-current;
        }
    }
protected:
    base current; 
    base end_first;
    base begin_second;
    bool in_first;
};
template<class base>
std::pair<concatenated_range_iterator<base>,concatenated_range_iterator<base>>
    concatenate_ranges(base first1, base end1, base first2, base end2)
{
    return std::pair<concatenated_range_iterator<base>,concatenated_range_iterator<base>>(
        concatenated_range_iterator<base>(true, first1, end1, first2, end2),
        concatenated_range_iterator<base>(false, first1, end1, first2, end2)
        );
}


#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vars = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    
    auto range = concatenate_ranges(vars.begin(), vars.begin()+4, vars.begin()+5, vars.end());
    for(auto iter=range.first; iter!=range.second; ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << ' ';
}
```

Comment: This is a typical example of the folly of abusing `auto`.  Write out the type for `range0`, and the answer should be obvious.

Comment: @JamesKanze: thanks, but can you be more specific? What is the type of range0? i.e. by what should I replace the 'auto' keyword?

Comment: That's the whole point.  If you don't know the type of `range0`, you can't do anything with it.  Once you know the type, you can start from there figuring out what you need to do.

Comment: Look at the return value for concatenate_ranges

Comment: @Jack: Thanks. Ok I have: 'std::pair<concatenated_range_iterator<base>,concatenated_range_iterator<base>>'. Is this what you are referring to? And if yes, how do you use this information?

Comment: Yes, so what you're telling it to do is make a reverse_iterator from a concatenated_range_iterator which it will have no idea how to do. Instead create the reverse iterator off of the base container. I can't get to his code to see it, but something tells me there isn't a "base container" so you will probably have to rewrite some of his code

Comment: I can get to the SO post, but when I click where he put the code up it's blank for me. Basically he's implementing a forward iterator if I had to guess, you just need to implement the same logic he did... backwards.

Comment: @JamesKanze One of the biggest purposes of auto is to reduce the amount of typing needed to support template based generic returns. This is not the folly of using auto; this is the *point* of using it.

Comment: @Alice The purpose of `auto` is partially to reduce typing, especially _within_ templates.  And in contexts where there is a very rigorously established convention with regards to the type, e.g. `auto iter = v.begin()`.  (But even this only applies to simple types, with very strict protocols.)  Using except in such special cases is abuse, an anti-pattern which makes the code significantly less readable.

Comment: @JamesKanze Within templates as well as variables that depend on the return of a generic functor? This is one such variable, and this context is one that was a driving force for people to push for auto, and prior to it, BOOST_AUTO. To say that this example, which would not be out of place in a standards discussion, is "abuse" is silly. Using the extended type declaration gains nothing, and wastes 125 characters, as seen below in n.m.'s answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are instantiating the `reverse_iterator` template incorrectly. Try

```
auto fst = std::reverse_iterator<decltype(range0.second)>(range0.second);
auto snd = std::reverse_iterator<decltype(range0.first)>(range0.first);
```

To make the types more explicit:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator VI;
typedef concatenated_range_iterator<VI> CRVI;
typedef std::pair<CRVI, CRVI> CRVIrange;
CRVIrange range0 = concatenate_ranges(vars.begin(), vars.begin()+2,
                                       vars.begin()+5, vars.end());

typedef std::reverse_iterator<CRVI> RCRVI;
RCRVI fst = RCRVI(range0.second);
RCRVI snd = RCRVI(range0.first);
```

I would hate to write down something like `std::pair<std::reverse_iterator<concatenated_range_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>>,std::reverse_iterator<concatenated_range_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>>>`!

Comment: Thanks, I think it works great! Still, would lit be possible adapt your code so that the type of fst, snd, range0 is made explicit? This is mostly to address James Kanze comments (just below my question): I didn't realize it at first but reading their comments I can see why that's better practice. –

Comment: Better practice? I do not necessarily agree with that, but here are explicit types anyway.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, personally I also find your original version more readable, but other users seemed to be adamant about it:). Anyway thanks for the working code!

Comment: The version using auto should always be the preferred one.